# Openpyxl wb.save() TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, typeerror, openpyxl

I've come across an error when using the openpyxl wb.save() function and am baffled about why its occurring. It seems to only occur when I run the code in a certain way but I can't interpret the errors to understand why this might be happening. The code is formatting a number of excel spreadsheet tabs and exporting them into one workbook. I've seen a few similar posts with this error but are all in relation to the load_workbook() function.

Any support would be much appreciated!

This is the function that's causing these errors.

```
wb.save(output_filename)
```

The below extracts are the two errors that appear in the terminal.

```
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 55, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
```

The is the referenced block of code which triggers the TypeError

```
def _convert(expected_type, value):
    """
    Check value is of or can be converted to expected type.
    """
    if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
        try:
            value = expected_type(value)
        except:
            raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
    return value
```

I will eternally be in your debt you can help me with this!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file you're trying to read is defective.

Comment: Is there an easy way I can identify or assess how the file is defective?

Comment: Validate it will the OOXML validtor. Basically, in styles.xlsx there fill elements may have no attribute but must contain either a gradient or a pattern fill.